# Please let me know correct scriptural reference which mentions that Ram naam jaap or bhakti is necessary to worship Hanuman?

Tags: scripture, rama, hanuman, bhakti, reference-request

Is it necessary for a Hanuman devotee to worship Shri Ram. If yes, please provide scriptural reference as a proof.

Comment: If worship is done following the methods of Tantras using the Murti Swarupas mentioned in them then possibly there is no such requirement (https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/28/murtis-of-hanuman/) .. but in the normal devotional form of worship, that is popular among the masses, such a requirement is possibly mentioned .. BTW welcome back after a long interval :)

Comment: @Rickross you mean if any form of hanuman murti is there, then Ram nama chanting is not required? Yeah  thanks. How r u?

Comment: Yes .. these forms are independent of Ramchandra .. they are Tantric forms of Hanuman .. 9 such forms are there. Yes I am fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In goswami Tulsidas krut Hanuman ashtakam, it is written

यत्र यत्र रघुनाथ कीर्तनं
तत्र तत्र कृतमस्तकाञ्जलिम् ।

भाष्पवारि परिपूर्ण लोचनं
मारुतिं नमत राक्षसान्तकम् ।।

अर्थ : जहां -जहां भगवान श्रीरघुनाथकी  संकीर्तन होता है, वहां शरणागत मस्तक, जुडे  हुए हस्त कमल और नेत्रोंमें भावपूर्ण आनंद अश्रुके साथ उपस्थित होते हैं , ऐसे राक्षसोंका संहार करनेवाले, श्रीहनुमानको हमारा कोटिश: प्रणाम !

Also in Hanuman samhita, hanumanji says:-

केवलं रामनाम्नैव सदा मम् जीवन मुने।

सत्यं वदामि सर्वस्वम् इदम् एकम् सदा मम्।

Only ram naam is my life. I m saying truth, my everything is only ram naam.
Also it is said in same scripture, that whenever ram naam jap is done by sadhakas or anyone, he immediately comes and fulfills and give protection to sadhak

Also in bhusundi ramayan, Hanuman ji says:-

जपामि रामनाम अहं स्मरामि रघुपंगवम्।
भजामि नित्यं काकुस्त्थं वीक्षे दशरथात्मजम्।।

I always do jap of Shri Ram naam, i always remember shri Ram. I always worship Rama, the son of Dasratha. I always worship him.

So whenever Shri Ram naam is uttered (jap) , he immediately comes.
्